# Book recommendation: Sobolev spaces.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have already read the standard part in Evan's PDE text book. However, in his book, the theorems like Sobolev embeddings only involve bounded domain, and it talks just a little about fractional Sobolev spaces. I want to look at a book that is deeper than this. I know the book written by Adams is a standard book, but this book is much more than what I need right now.
Can someone recommend me a book for Sobolev space that is readable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there specific types of Sobolev spaces you want to use? You could look for them in Adams’ book and read only that part. Stein’s book Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions also discusses many types.

Comment: Adams and Fournier is the classical reference for general results on Sobolev spaces.

Comment: There’s the books “A first course in Sobolev Spaces” and “A first course in fractional Sobolev spaces” by Giovanni Leoni

Answer (score 2):

G. Folland's TATA lectures on PDE give a terrific quick-intro to Sobolev spaces on $\mathbb R^n$, via Fourier transforms. That was what finally convinced me that the idea was useful. :) The possibility of using Fourier transforms "globally" is a great simplifier.

It is also possible to do "global" Sobolev theory on (products of) *circles*, via Fourier series. Obviously, this will be even simpler than the Fourier transform scenario.